# Why this holding event mouse doesn't for a canvas painting?

Tags: javascript

Can somebody give me some help?, I don't understand why it doesn't work, I tried everything but I just don't understand it, I'm beginner.

I'm trying to make a holding mouse event for a canvas painting, I tried making a while loop you hold it and it will paint in the canvas but it doesn't work so I tried making the loop say "Hello" in console... but it doesn't work.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", holding)
document.addEventListener("mouseup", noHolding)

var hold;

function holding(){
    hold = true;
    console.log("hold: " + hold)
}


function noHolding(){ 
    hold = false;
    console.log("hold: " +  hold)
}


while(hold == true){
    console.log("Holding")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about the order of execution.
Your code gets executed line by line (more or less). So in your example these are the steps:

1. declare function `holding`
2. declare function `noHolding`
3. declare variable `hold`
4. bind `holding` to the `mousedown` event
5. bind `noHolding` to the `moueup` event
6. define function `holding`
7. define function `noHolding`
8. loop while `hold == true`

   - the value of hold, at this point in time is `undefined`, so the loop does not run
9. finish execution

*`function` and `var` declarations are moved (hoisted) to the top of their function, or global if not in a function, scope.*

Later when you press down your mouse button `hold` will be set to `true` but the `while(hold==true)` statement has already been executed and will not run again.

You should avoid loops in javascript that will run for more than a few milliseconds because it they will stop any other code from running (generally).

You can instead use the [mousemove event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event). (example included)

Example from MDN:

```js
// When true, moving the mouse draws on the canvas
let isDrawing = false;
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

const myPics = document.getElementById('myPics');
const context = myPics.getContext('2d');

// The x and y offset of the canvas from the edge of the page
const rect = myPics.getBoundingClientRect();

// Add the event listeners for mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup
myPics.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  isDrawing = true;
});

myPics.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (isDrawing === true) {
    drawLine(context, x, y, e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top);
    x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  if (isDrawing === true) {
    drawLine(context, x, y, e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    isDrawing = false;
  }
});

function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 560px;
  height: 360px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Drawing with mouse events</h1>
<canvas id="myPics" width="560" height="360"></canvas>
```

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you consider accepting it so that it can help others too. :)